# Does Office 2003 represent a security risk on a managed environment, due to end of mainstream support?

Tags: security, microsoft-office

With the [end of mainstream support for Office 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/HA102294401033.aspx), it's tempting to retire Office 2003 from a managed network altogether (and replace with Office 2007, in our environment), but there are pockets of resistance (e.g. users who contractually share Access 2003 databases with large consortia internationally).  **Security is an effective rationale to compel users to upgrade, when it's defensible**.

Does Office 2003 represent a security threat on a managed network, due to end of mainstream support?

EDIT: Much of our user base, and our back end, are moving to Office 2007 for Exchange and Sharepoint integration advantages - so sticking with 2003 in general is not the plan, and heterogeneity is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 2003 is safe, as long as you are running SP3 and patching. Microsoft continues to provide security fixes for the duration of the extended support cycle.

We had a similar issue with Access -- some users had Access applications that were essential to whatever they were doing. The solution is pretty simple -- you just configure the installer to leave Access 2003 behind! [KB928091 discuses install order and some gotchas](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/928091). (*The big one is that you can only have one version of Outlook*)

You're actually just as well that you've waited, Office 2007 SP2 fixed all sorts of pretty serious errors, particularly with Outlook calendaring with Exchange 2007.

Comment: Thanks!  So, **Access 2003 is compatible with the other pieces of Office 2007?**

Comment: Everything except Outlook can co-exist. I added a link to a Microsoft KB article that discusses install order and some of the issues. Also, this is a perfect use case for software virtualization like Softgrid or thinstall. You may already own SoftGrid through your MS ELA and may own Thinstall if you have a VMWare license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that so long as there is a vector by which outside Microsoft Office 2003 documents can get to the PCs w/ Office 2003 installed it could legitimately argued that there is vulnerability. Having said that, I don't know what Microsoft's policy on issuing security-related patches is after the "mainstream support" period ends. A lot of companies are sticking with Office 2003 for now, and so long as there are enough Customers to create a ruckus when new "0 day vulnerabilities" in the Office 2003 products are found I would expect that Microsoft will continue to release security-related patches.

(Insert argument for open source software here... You can pay anyone you want to continue to "support" open source software w/o artifical "upgrade treadmills", etc...)

Comment: During the extended support period, through 14 April 2014, security hotfixes are provided.

Comment: That would seem to answer your question.

Comment: Not really - else I would not have asked.  It's clear that Microsoft is providing less than full support for Office 2003, and it's likely that 2003 gets a lower priority for security fixes than 2007 (it's a zero-sum game).  Also, there may be more to security in a complex app suite than security hotfixes.  I'm asking the SF experts whether they consider the lower level of support provided during non-mainstream support to be a security risk.